# Understanding the Point of Declaring an Array in Bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to understand the point of ever explicitly declaring an array in bash.  The course I'm doing states that you should create an array by using the command:

```
$ declare -a ARRAYNAME
```

I actually never knew about this command because I've never done my arrays like that.  As an example, I wrote the script below and then deleted the 1st line of the file.  The results were the same.  Which begs the question, what's the **actual point** of ever using this "$ declare -a" statement since my course states that apparently this declare statement **must** be used (which I proved wrong)?

```
$ cat test6
declare -a car_models
car_models=( honda toyota bmw )

for i in "${!car_models[@]}"
do
echo " $i ${car_models[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: afaik there is no actual difference, you can either create an array with `declare -a array_name` or `array_name=()`.

Comment: "must be used" is not the same as "you should".  and the answer to using it is "readability". This question has nothing to do with Ubuntu; it is a coding behaviour question. seems more like an stackoverflow topic to me. Like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742062/why-are-declare-f-and-declare-a-needed-in-bash-scripts

Comment: Ok thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason I am aware of why you would *have* to declare it other than clarity and readibility of your code since declaring it is a clear indication to the next person who reads your code that "Hey, this variable will hold an indexed array".

On the other hand, declaring *associative* arrays is indeed useful. COnsider this example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for i in {a..c}; do
  badArray[$i]="foo $i"
done

declare -A goodArray
for i in {a..c}; do
  goodArray[$i]="foo $i"
done

for i in {a..d}; do
  printf 'badArray value for key "%s" is: %s, goodArray value is: %s\n' \
         "$i" "${badArray[$i]}" "${goodArray[$i]}"
done

echo "BAD: ${badArray[@]}"
echo "BAD: ${goodArray[@]}"
```

Running that gives:

```
$ foo.sh
badArray value for key "a" is: foo d, goodArray value is: foo a
badArray value for key "b" is: foo d, goodArray value is: foo b
badArray value for key "c" is: foo d, goodArray value is: foo c
badArray value for key "d" is: foo d, goodArray value is: foo d

BAD: foo c
BAD: foo c foo b foo a
```

As you can see, unlike with regular indexed arrays, if you don't declare the array as associative with `declare -A` it doesn't work.